# Dynamic Google Maps Location for PHP and MySQL Driven

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database driven site where it fetches the address and the address is shown on a google map. Here is the string containing the the google map embedments. I dont have the latitudes of the locates but i have the Address and area. The locations are not appearing .

```
<?php  $add = $row_rsDoc['Address'];
$address = str_replace(" ","+",$add);
$gtown = str_replace(" ","+",$row_rsDoc['Town']);
$gprov = str_replace(" ","+",$row_rsDoc['Province']);

$googlestr=$address.','.'+'.$gtown.','.'+'.$gprov;
echo $googlestr;
?>
<th width="446" class="entry" scope="col"><iframe width="441" height="243" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.za/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?php echo $googlestr; ?>&amp;aq=&amp;sll=-26.178375,28.033719&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `str_replace()` use `urlencode()` (see documentation for [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php))

Also, you're including location coords in your URL, try use this:

```
<th width="446" class="entry" scope="col"><iframe width="441" height="243" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.za/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?php echo $googlestr; ?>&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to geocode your addresses to get long/lat and then use markers and an overlay to embed the markers onto your google map.  There's a great example of how to do this on the google maps docs both how to apply static markers and how to geocode.

The process goes something like this.

On address add -> request geocode -> store returned long/lat into db -> on map load do call back via ajax to a php page which returns an array of your long/lats to mark on the map.

Its exactly how I do it and it minimises the number of actual queries you have to do against the google api since its limited requests for free users.  If you want actual code let me know I can copy and paste out of one of my apps which does exactly this.